Unity_Animation_Twice_Acting_Problem
enter image description hereenter image description here
This attack Animation has worked twice, Why is this happening?
Animation RoopTime is off and I tried off the Fixed Duration but it's not working.
I tried the animation Trigger off by the next code and rebuilding the animation state.

Am.. I found a problem
I did't make coolTime system that is a reason..
